# Первая буква предложения заглавная

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть textarea, куда пользователь вводит неотформатированный текст. По нажатию на кнопку в этот же блок вставляется отформатированный текст.

Вопрос в том, что не могу понять, как перевести первую букву каждого предложения в верхний регистр, а остальные в нижний.

Я так понимаю, нужно регулярной выбрать все буквы и цифры, которые идут после точки, знаков вопроса и восклицания (тут ещё вопрос, как учесть возможность наличия или отсутствия пробела после знака). После этого заменить найденный символы на такие же, но в верхнем регистре.

Помогите понять алгоритм и ткните регулярной или примером. Спасибо

Comment: **отформатированный/неотформатированный**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.replace(/((?:^|[.?!])\s*)([a-zа-яё])/g, function (m, tail, ch) {
  return tail + ch.toUpperCase();
});
```

А лучше даже так:

```
str.replace(/((?:^|[.?!])+\s*)(.)/g, function (m, tail, ch) {
  return tail + ch.toUpperCase();
});
```

Фикс для случая `что-то?? ?такое`:

```
str.replace(/((?:(?:^|[.?!])\s*)+)(.)/g, function (m, tail, ch) {
  return tail + ch.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Получается вот такая регулярка:

```
/([\w\s\d]+)*\s?[.!?]\s?/g
```

Соответственно в первую выборку попадут все предложения без точки. Дальше алгоритм прост, выбираешь первую букву каждого предложения и натравливаешь на нее toUpperСase, на остальные toLowerCase. Есть только тут один нюанс, если после точки есть пробел, он попадает в следующее предложение. Значит нужно добавить также проверку на это.

Comment: Спасибо. Сегодня попробую допилить ваш пример.

Comment: `[\.|\!|\?]` рекомендую прочитать что-нибудь про регулярные выражения.

Comment: Спасибо. Чуть-чуть подправил.